# What is the equivalent for an Oracle associative array in SQL Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql, plsql

I have implemented an associative array as below in Oracle:

```
TYPE cri_lit_sat_map IS TABLE OF BOOLEAN INDEX BY VARCHAR2(500);   
cri_map cri_lit_sat_map;
```

Please let me know the equivalent SQL Server construct.

Comment: probably a table variable or temp table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

Comment: or this:

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[temp_tab] (@flag INT = 0)
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
      RETURN
         SELECT * FROM another_tab
        WHERE expr = @flag
    GO

Comment: Ok can I do select from and insert into the Temp table or table variable in the User defined function. So that I could use it to modify and refer to data across multiple cursor rows?